# How do I merge two Cassandra clusters with no downtime?

Tags: cassandra

We have two Cassandra clusters with different cluster_name that continuously receive different data.

Cluster A => keyspaceA

Cluster B => keyspaceB

We are looking to merge the two clusters either by creating an additional cluster and then replicate data from the first cluster and then from the second cluster, or by replicating data from cluster B to cluster A.
Both solutions would cause downtime for the second cluster in order to set up the nodes.

Is it possible to merge the two Cassandra clusters with no downtime?

Comment: This really belongs on the dba stack exchange site (dba.stackexchange.com), not Stack Overflow - it's unrelated to programming, and very specific to Cassandra and databases in general.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never, ever do this. This is a very bad idea.

First of all, it is not possible to change the name of a cluster (`cluster_name`) once a node has been started.

Second, attempts to re-provision a running node by adding it to another cluster will "poison" the cluster's schema and result in full data loss.

This operation is not recommended, supported or tested. Do not attempt to do it. Cheers!